# Moving Cache Profiles Settings to appsettings.json in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to be able to edit the cache profile settings in my config.json file. You could do something similar in ASP.NET 4.6 with the web.config file. This is what I have now:

```
services.ConfigureMvc(
    mvcOptions =>
    {
        mvcOptions.CacheProfiles.Add(
            "RobotsText",
            new CacheProfile()
            {
                Duration = 86400,
                Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any,
                // VaryByParam = "none" // Does not exist in MVC 6 yet.
            });
    });
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
services.ConfigureMvc(
    mvcOptions =>
    {
        var cacheProfiles = ConfigurationBinder.Bind<Dictionary<string, CacheProfile>>(
            Configuration.GetConfigurationSection("CacheProfiles"));
        foreach (var keyValuePair in cacheProfiles)
        {
            mvcOptions.CacheProfiles.Add(keyValuePair);
        }
    });
```

With my `appsettings.json` file looking like this:

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "SiteTitle": "ASP.NET MVC Boilerplate"
  }
  "CacheProfiles" : {
    "RobotsText" : {
      "Duration" : 86400,
      "Location" : "Any",
    }
  }
}
```

However, I have not been able to get this to work. I keep getting reflection errors upon trying to bind the configuration section.

Comment: Take a look at the tests using this: https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Binder.Test/ConfigurationCollectionBindingTests.cs#L358

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
public class CacheProfileSettings
{
    public Dictionary<string, CacheProfile> CacheProfiles { get; set; }
}

//------------------------------------------

var cacheProfileSettings = ConfigurationBinder.Bind<CacheProfileSettings>(config.GetConfigurationSection("CacheProfiles"));
var cacheProfile = cacheProfileSettings.CacheProfiles["RobotsText"];
```

Comment: So I need a wrapper around my dictionary and can't bind to a dictionary directly?