# OutputCache / ResponseCache VaryByParam

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-caching, asp.net-core-1.0

`ResponseCache` is somewhat a replacement for `OutputCache`; however, I would like to do server side caching as well as per parameter input.

According to some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31054389/1284637) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27311194/1284637), I should be using `IMemoryCache` or `IDistributedCache` to do this. I'm particularly interested in caching on controllers where the parameter is different, previously done in asp.net 4 with `OutputCache` and `VaryByParam` like so:

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "Medium", VaryByParam = "id", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
public ActionResult Index(long id) 
{ 
    ///...
}
```

How would I go about replicating this in asp.net core?

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: Just a heads up: while you are referring to  .Net Framework OutputCacheAttribute there is also a new one in Asp.net Core 7. See my answer.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to change the cache by all request query parameters in all requests in the controller:

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 20, VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "*" })]
public class ActiveSectionController : ControllerBase
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

First be sure you are using ASP.NET Core 1.1 or higher.

Then use a code similar to this on your controller method:

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 300, VaryByQueryKeys = new string[] { "date_ref" } )]
public IActionResult Quality(DateTime date_ref)
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware

Answer (score 5):

Asp.Net Core 7 added [Output Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/output?view=aspnetcore-7.0) middleware. This does exactly what you want, i.e. server caching. This is not to be confused with the old .Net Framework [OutputCacheAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) you are referring to.

The main difference between OutputCache and ResponseCache:

- OutputCache is just for server caching (it doesn't even have a Location property)
- ResponseCache is mainly for browser caching and uses the [HTTP cache headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)

You can probably use them both for the same endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

use this in asp.net core

```
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "TelegraphCache", VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "id" })]
```

Comment: But this is not caching when deployed on server. 
Request 1 -> response time 5 seconds
Request 2 -> Response time is also 5 seconds but it returns Age and cache controls max age 
Any thing missing while deploying on server. Pls help

Answer (score 1):

For someone whose looking for the answer... after all there is [IMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.1) but not as pretty as old days `ActionFilterAttribute` But with more flexibility.
Long story short (for .Net core 2.1 mostly By Microsoft docs + my understands):
1- Add `services.AddMemoryCache();` service into `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs` file.
2- inject the service into your controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  private IMemoryCache _cache;

  public HomeController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
  {
      _cache = memoryCache;
  }
```

3- arbitrarily (in order to prevent typo) declare a static class which holds bunch of key's names:

```
public static class CacheKeys
{
  public static string SomeKey { get { return "someKey"; } }
  public static string AnotherKey { get { return "anotherKey"; } }
  ... list could be goes on based on your needs ...
```

I prefer to declare an `enum` instead:
`public enum CacheKeys { someKey, anotherKey, ...}`
3- Play with it in actionMethods like this:
For get cached value: `_cache.TryGetValue(CacheKeys.SomeKey, out someValue)`
Or Reset value if `TryGetValue` if fail:

```
_cache.Set(CacheKeys.SomeKey, 
           newCachableValue, 
           new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)));
```

END.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, none of the followings produce the expected cached-by-unique-parameters-values. Always returns the initial result:

`VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "*" }`

`VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "searchparam" }`

given `public async Task<IActionResult> Search([FromQuery] string searchparam)`

Solution is prefix it with a `$`, that is
`VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "$searchparam" }`