# How to Use ResponseCache in asp.net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I tried following the answer (highest voted, not accepted) found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304210/how-do-i-apply-the-outputcache-attribute-on-a-method-in-a-vnext-project) to implement `ResponseCaching` in my asp.net core 2.0 project.

However I get the error:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Internal.IResponseCachingPolicyProvider' from root provider.
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider)

The steps I've taken are:

1 Add the Interface binding in Startup like so:

```
    services.AddScoped<IResponseCachingPolicyProvider, ResponseCachingPolicyProvider>();
```

2 Add the response caching middleware like so:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
{
    application
        .UseResponseCaching()
        .UseMvc();
}
```

3 Added the Tag to my Controller like so:

```
 [ResponseCache(Duration = 3600)]
```

I am trying to get the same behaviour as adding `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]` Wouldve had in the past asp.net versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the necessary services for response caching, you should use this extension method in `ConfigureServices` of the `Startup` class:

```
services.AddResponseCaching();
```

You can see the source code for it here: https://github.com/aspnet/ResponseCaching/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching/ResponseCachingServicesExtensions.cs#L21

Comment: Thanks, thats it? I don't need to remove or edit any of the things I've added so far (see three steps)? Because just adding that I still get the same error.

Comment: You can skip step 1 at least since the extension method does that too.

Comment: Since it actually needs to be singleton-scope. It gets resolved in the response caching middleware constructor, which only runs once.